# Checking if two elements in a tuple have the same value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an tuple containing 100 string values (say). Now, I want to check if two string elements there in the tuple are same?

I tried to do something like this with nested loops:

```py
def hasDuplicates(arr: tuple):
    ctr = 0
    # arr looks something like this & len(arr) == 100
    # arr = ('abc', 'bcd', 'sdf', 'abc', 'pqr', ...)
    for m in arr:
        for n in arr:
            if n == m:
                ctr += 1
    # while looping, len(arr) times every element 
    # will be compared with itself
    if ctr > len(arr):
        return True
    return False
```

...which worked but I think there is a better work around for this. Can anyone provide a better solution to this? :)

Comment: Well, that is not a list it is a tuple

Comment: I think this question should be on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: if you just want to check if there are at least one duplicate element, then you can convert to set and compare lengths:
`len(set(arr)) == arr`  if true, then no duplicates are there
not sure if you care about officiency, but you should aim in O(n) solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can just convert your `tuple` to a `set` and check whether it has the same length as the original tuple.

```
def has_duplicates(iterable):
    l = list(iterable) # in case iterable is an iterator
    return len(set(l)) != len(l)
```

Demo:

```
>>> tup = ('abc', 'bcd', 'sdf', 'abc', 'pqr')
>>> has_duplicates(tup)
>>> True
>>> has_duplicates(range(100))
>>> False
```

Won't work for infinite iterators :)

**~edit~**

A more general version that does not have to build a potentially long `list` and `set` upfront:

```
def has_duplicates(iterable):
    seen = set()
    for x in iterable:
        if x in seen:
            return True
        seen.add(x)
    return False
```

Of course, both versions require the elements of your iterable to be hashable.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check this using `any` keyword and `count` method from `list` object:

```
arr = ('abc', 'bcd', 'sdf', 'abc', 'pqr')

def sameStrings(arr):
  return any(arr.count(elem)>1 for elem in list(arr))

print(sameStrings(arr))
```

Output:

```
True
```

**Edit**

Updating answer with proposed solution by @timgeb using `Counter` from `collections` module:

```
from collections import Counter

arr = ('abc', 'bcd', 'sdf', 'abc', 'pqr')

def sameStrings(arr):
  myCounter = Counter(list(arr))
  return max(myCounter.values())>1

print(sameStrings(arr))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: Note that `count` iterates over the whole sequence each time it is called, which makes this an `O(n**2)` algorithm. If you want to count, I suggest using a `collections.Counter` and check whether `max(mycounter.values()) == 1`.

Comment: Worked perfectly but I noticed that this was slower during execution. Thanks for this!

Comment: @timgeb updated my answer. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

```
has_duplicates = len(set(some_tuple)) == 1
```